# Absolute Elements Sums

Tags: python, algorithm, search, binary-search, bisect

I was trying to solve this problem on Hackerrank.
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/playing-with-numbers/problem

Given an array of integers, you must answer a number of queries. Each query consists of a single integer, x, and is performed as follows:

- Add x to each element of the array, permanently modifying it for any future queries.
- Find the absolute value of each element in the array and print the sum of the absolute values on a new line.

Can someone explain this solution to me? 
I didn't quite understand the need to search for `-q` in the array `n = bisect_left(arr, -q)` and this line `(Sc[-1] - 2 * Sc[n] + q * (N - 2 * n)`.

```
from bisect import bisect_left
def playingWithNumbers(arr, queries):
    N = len(arr)
    res = []

    # Calculate cummulative sum of arr
    arr = sorted(arr)
    Sc = [0]
    for x in arr:
        Sc.append(x+Sc[-1])

    q = 0
    for x in queries:
        q += x
        n = bisect_left(arr, -q)
        res.append((Sc[-1] - 2 * Sc[n] + q * (N - 2 * n)))
    return res
```

Thank you

Comment: That's not the solution to what you ask. There's cumulative sum and search via bisection, not incrementing all elements by x and finding sum of absolute values... You could just run this code with provided examples as see for yourself.

Comment: Yes, it's actually one of the solutions from the leaderboard. I tried running this code, but didn't fully understand why they used those terms and the idea of the code.

Comment: Looks like he sorted the array (I'm not a Python guy). But to solve this problem, you don't need to sort the array, there are two tasks, 1) add x to every element of array and 2) find the sum of all array elements regardless of sign. These two task can be done under one loop. So, O(n) complexity.

Comment: @ManojBanik After OP's comment I got the solution and am now writing a long explanation. It's a correct solution, just a smartass one. ;) Those two tasks are repeated many times, so it's `O(n*m)` naively, this solution above is `O(nlogn)` only because of sorting (literally sorting + O(n+m)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it's actually one of the solutions from the leaderboard. I tried running this code, but didn't fully understand why they used those terms and the idea of the code

Okay, I see this now... It's a "smartass" way of calculating it. I actually thought about this idea when I read the task but I didn't thought of the specifics.

Idea is: When you add `x` to each element, that element's absolute value changes by at most `x` - drops when you add to negative/subtract from positive, rises when you add to positive/subtracts from negative.

Having a cumulative sum of a sorted list allows you to not go through the list each time and add, and sum, but to just calculate the value.

---

Let's analyse it by taking the example input from the site:

```
3
-1 2 -3
3
1 -2 3
```

Our function gets: `arr = [-1, 2, -3]; queries = [1, -2, 3]`

After sorting into `arr = [-3, -1, 2]` (let's say those are `a,b,c` - letters are better at explaining *why* this works) we get our cumulative sum `Sc = [0, -3, -4, -2]` (`0, a, a+b, a+b+c`).

Now starts the smarty-pants part:

`-q` is where our values turn over in the `arr` - that is, where adding `q` would go over 0, making the absolute value rise, instead of drop

Let's translate this `res.append((Sc[-1] - 2 * Sc[n] + q * (N - 2 * n)))` one-by-one:

1. `Sc[-1]` is the sum (`a+b+c`)
2. let's take `q*N` first, it's how the whole sum changed when adding `q` (all `x` values up to this point) to each element
3. Let's take `- 2 * Sc[n]` and `q * (-2*n)` together: `-2 * (Sc[n] + q*n)` - this is the turnover point I mentioned - if we have a negative number (we looked up `-q`, but we add `q` to it), `neg - 2*abs(neg) = abs(neg)`, we use `Sc` and `*n` to turn over all the negative values.

---

This solution's complexity is `O(max(n,m)*logn)` - because of the sorting. The cumulative sum thing is `O(n)`, the smart loop is `O(m*logn)` (bisection is `O(logn)`, I forgot it in the comment).

Naive method with changing the values in the list would be `O(n*m)` - `m` times going through `n`-length list.

Comment: @ManojBanik Negative index `[-i]` is the same as `[len(arr)-i]`. ;)