# Reducing complexity to find the absolute sum of an array elements

Tags: java, performance, time-complexity

I got this problem on Hackerrank.
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/playing-with-numbers/problem

Given an array of integers, you must answer a number of queries. Each query consists of a single integer, x and is performed as follows:

- Add x to each element of the array, permanently modifying it for any future queries.
- Find the absolute value of each element in the array and print the sum of the absolute values on a new line.

All I need to complete the following method,

```
static int[] solution(int[] arr, int[] queries)
```

Here, `arr` is the array with `n` elements
and `queries` contain all the `x` that I need to add with each value of the array `arr` and then get the absolute sum of the elements of `arr`. So the resultant array will be the same size as array `queries`, say that size is `m`. The method will return an array of `m` elements.

Below is my implementation.

```
       static int[] solution(int[] arr, int[] queries)
       {

          int[] result = new int[queries.length];

          for (int i = 0; i < queries.length; i++)
          {
             int total = 0;

             for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++)
             {
                arr[j] += queries[i];

                if (arr[j] > 0)
                   total += arr[j];
                else
                   total -= arr[j];
             }
             result[i] = total;
          }

          return result;
       }
```

It works fine, its complexity is `O(mn)`, but I need to do it with a complexity of something `O(nlog_m)` or `O(mlog_n)` or close to that.

Comment: Questions asking for help optimizing code that is currently working are usually better suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com. You might want to consider migrating your question over to there.

Comment: At first I asked there codereview.stackexchange.com, someone said since I'm looking for new implementation, I should ask here. So I delete that, and ask here.

Comment: You can keep `arr`'s sum in an external variable, along with the aggregated sum of the integers in `queries`

Comment: @azurefrog Not really, CR is more than just an optimization. There's not much of OP's code and there's no point in making it nicer it when it needs a full rewrite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Inspired** by the explanation given by **h4z3** in the following link,
[Absolute Elements Sums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59375023/absolute-elements-sums/59376000#comment104948813_59376000)

I've implemented the idea in Java,

**The complexity is O(n log n).**

```
   static int bisect_left(int[] num, int x)
   {
      int low = 0;
      int high = num.length - 1;

      while (low < high)
      {
         int mid = (low + high) / 2;

         if (num[mid] >= x)
            high = mid - 1;
         else
            low = mid + 1;
      }

      return (num[low] < x) ? low + 1 : low;
   }

   static int[] solution(int[] arr, int[] queries)
   {
      Arrays.sort(arr); // O(n log n)

      int N = arr.length;

      int[] results = new int[queries.length];
      int[] sc = new int[N + 1];
      sc[0] = 0;
      sc[1] = arr[0];

      for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
         sc[i + 1] = sc[i] + arr[i];

      int q = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < queries.length; i++)  //  O(m)
      {
         q += queries[i];

         int n = bisect_left(arr, -q);  //  O(log n)

         results[i] = sc[N] + q * N - 2 * (sc[n] + q * n);
      }

      return results;
   }
```

Comment: This is a smart solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWER**

Essentially, if you know how many numbers will be positive and how many will be negative, you can just multiply both of these counts by the accumulated query total (and *-1 for negatives).

Work out the total count for how many -/+ there are and the total sum for all these values at each step. E.g. add +1 to all until all negatives are positive, and add -1 to all until all positives are negative, store the results of each step (the -/+ counts and total sum of all -/+ values).

You can now reference the total sum and the total -/+ counts for each step to work out the result of each query.

You will also **need** to change the return type of both the playingWithNumbers method and the result array, from int to long!

```
static long[] playingWithNumbers(int[] arr, int[] queries) {

    long[] results = new long[queries.length];

    List<Integer> negatives = new ArrayList<>(arr.length);
    List<Integer> positives = new ArrayList<>(arr.length);

    long negativeSum = 0;
    long positiveSum = 0;
    for (int i : arr) {
        if (i < 0) {
            negatives.add(i);
            negativeSum += i;
        } else {
            positives.add(i);
            positiveSum += i;
        }
    }
    int negativeCount = negatives.size();
    int positiveCount = positives.size();
    Collections.sort(negatives);
    Collections.sort(positives);

    Map<Integer, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<>(arr.length);
    Map<Integer, Long> sumMap = new HashMap<>(arr.length);
    long totalSum = positiveSum + (negativeSum * -1);
    countMap.put(0, negativeCount);
    sumMap.put(0, totalSum);

    if (positiveCount != 0) {
        long tmpTotalSum = totalSum;
        int tmpNegativeCount = negativeCount;
        int increment = negativeCount - positiveCount;
        int index = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= positives.get(positiveCount - 1) + 1; i++) {
            while (index != positives.size() && positives.get(index) - i == -1) {
                tmpNegativeCount++;
                increment += 2;
                index++;
            }
            tmpTotalSum += increment;
            countMap.put(i * -1, tmpNegativeCount);
            sumMap.put(i * -1, tmpTotalSum);
        }
    }

    if (negativeCount != 0) {
        long tmpTotalSum = totalSum;
        int tmpNegativeCount = negativeCount;
        int increment = positiveCount - negativeCount;
        int index = negativeCount - 1;

        for (int i = 1; i <= (negatives.get(0) - 1) * -1; i++) {
            int incrementNxt = 0;
            while (index != -1 && negatives.get(index) + i == 0) {
                tmpNegativeCount--;
                incrementNxt += 2;
                index--;
            }
            tmpTotalSum += increment;
            increment += incrementNxt;
            countMap.put(i, tmpNegativeCount);
            sumMap.put(i, tmpTotalSum);
        }
    }

    int maxNegative = positiveCount != 0 ? (positives.get(positiveCount - 1) + 1) * -1 : 0;
    int maxPositive = negativeCount != 0 ? ((negatives.get(0) - 1)) * -1 : 0;
    int totalCount = positiveCount + negativeCount;
    long accumulatedTotal = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < queries.length; i++) {
        accumulatedTotal += queries[i];

        if (accumulatedTotal >= maxNegative && accumulatedTotal <= maxPositive) {
            results[i] = sumMap.get((int)accumulatedTotal);
        } else if (accumulatedTotal < maxNegative) {
            long extra = maxNegative - accumulatedTotal;
            results[i] = sumMap.get(maxNegative) + countMap.get(maxNegative) * extra;
        } else {
            long extra = accumulatedTotal - maxPositive;
            results[i] = sumMap.get(maxPositive) + (totalCount - countMap.get(maxPositive)) * extra;
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

Comment: Could you please add few words that can describe your idea/technique. I would like to implement it in my way. Thanks.

Comment: I've updated my answer with more detail buddy. Thanks.

Comment: Your program produces wrong result. For arr[] = {0, -2, -3, 2} and queries[] = {-2, 4, -1} the output should be {11, 7, 7} but your code produces {9, 9, 7}. Have you checked your result with some sample inputs?

Comment: Yes, multiple test cases and it also passes all the test cases on Hackerrank. I get {11, 7, 7} result on my machine. Check you have copied the code correctly.

Comment: Please let me know the output for arr[] = {0, -2, -3, 2} and queries[] = {-2, 4, -1} by your program.

Comment: I get {11, 7, 7} result on my machine. Check you have copied the code correctly.

Comment: You are right. arr & queries were modified by my method before I call yours.

Comment: Thanks. Please upvote the answer if you found it useful :)

Comment: I will, please edit the answer a little bit, sorry for the down vote as it was a mistake. I upvoted your comment.

Answer (score -1):

```java
       static int[] solution(int[] arr, int[] queries)
       {

          int querySum = 0;
          for (int i; i < queries.length; i++) {
            querySum += queries[i];
          }

          for (int j; j < arr.length; j++) {
            arr[j] += querySum;
            arr[j] = Math.abs(arr[j]);
          }

          return arr;
       }
```

The complexity is O(n), additional memory consumption O(1)

Comment: You missed the "absolute value".

Comment: Hm, yep, you're right, but it doesn't change complexity nor memory consumption

Comment: Its still wrong @Alexey, For arr[] = {0, -2, -3, 2} and queries[] = {-2, 4, -1} the output should be {11, 7, 7}, your answer will produce array of size 4 regardless of queries size.