# How do I construct an algorithm for the given time-complexity?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

We have been taught how to calculate time-complexity for a given algorithm, but how do we do the reverse?
For example: write a code to calculate the square of a number with time complexity of theta(n).
Any other example will do too.

Comment: That means you are asked to write a program/algorithm whose complexity shouldn't exceed some limit. There are many examples, you can check this one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59399073/reducing-complexity-to-find-the-absolute-sum-of-an-array-elements

Comment: Thank you. I checked it out. Is there anything, in general, I can refer to?